# Event.Target.GetAttribute returns null

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura, button, aura-iteration

I'm creating and displaying lightning buttons in aura components dynamically. On click of each button, I'm trying to fetch its index using event.target.getAttribute. I'm able to get it but sporadically. Below is the code.

```
<div class="slds-grid slds-gutters product-btn">
  <aura:iteration items = "{!v.buttonList}" var  = "btn" indexVar = "index" >
    <div class="slds-col" data-row-index = "{!index}"> 
      <lightning:button  onclick="{!c.callJSController}" label="{!btn.key}"/>
    </div>
  </aura:iteration>
</div>

callJSController : function(cmp, event, helper) {
  let index = event.target.getAttribute("data-row-index"); //becomes null sometimes
}
```

Can anyone help me out what am I missing here or is there any other way to handle it efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) instead of `event.target` to get the reference to the button element, then you could access to the parent div via `parentElement`. `event.currentTarget` always refers to the element to which the event handler has been attached, while `event.target` identifies the element on which the event occurred and which may be its descendant.

```html
<aura:iteration items = "{!v.buttonList}" data-row-index="{!index}" var = "btn" indexVar = "index" >
    <div class="slds-col"> 
      <lightning:button onclick="{!c.callJSController}" label="{!btn.key}"/>
    </div>
</aura:iteration>
```

Moreover you don't need `getAttribute`: [`data-*` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset#accessing_values) can be set and read by the camelCase name/key as an object property of the dataset:

```js
callJSController : function(cmp, event, helper) {
  let index = event.currentTarget.parentElement.dataset.rowIndex;
}
```

Please note that `index` will be a `string`, not a `number`. If you need it as a `number`, you could use the [unary `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus) operator:

```js
callJSController : function(cmp, event, helper) {
  let index = +event.currentTarget.parentElement.dataset.rowIndex;
}
```

Comment: When trying to keep data-row-index in lightning button, facing this error "The attribute "data-row-index" was not found on the COMPONENT markup://lightning:button"

Comment: @sfdcdevsathy You're right, in aura we cannot set data attribute on standard component, I updated the answer.